# Resetting to previous unpushed comits and pushing them

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push, git-reset

Say I have :

- HEAD@{1} : A (unpushed)
- HEAD@{2} : B (unpushed)
- HEAD@{3} : C (unpushed)
- HEAD@{4} : D (unpushed)

If I am to reset to `HEAD@{4}` and push it, can I later reset to HEAD@{3}, push it, reset to HEAD@{2} and so on? Would I lose my following commits after I reset and push `HEAD@{4}` ?

Comment: What is an uncommitted commit? Did you mean not yet pushed?

Comment: Yes, precisely, will correct it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the configuration of your central repository (where you want to push to) if you are allowed to push a branch that has been reset to a previous commit. In many repositories this is not allowed on particular branches (e. g. master).

If you can do it, the commits are still there. You can find them when you know the git hash or try to find them with `git reflog`. When they are no longer reachable via a branch or tag backwards in history, they will be eventually removed by the garbage collector, maybe after four weeks (depends on configuration).

You will also keep the commits in your local copy of the repository unless you do a garbage collection.

If you want to be sure that you can restore these commits later on, you can branch or tag the latest commit befor resetting our current branch to an older commit.

Comment: At the moment I am in my master branch, I can very well see my commits with `git reflog` and switch between them. I am thinking of pushing them in order (from 4 to 1 and not 1 to 4), I am afraid if I branch the latest commit and push it, the previous ones will no longer be valid

Comment: If you push a commit, all previous commits will also be tranferred if not already present in the central repository.

Comment: You are right : the reason why I want to start from last and go to first is because the last commit includes all the previous ones, which takes a significant amount of time to push, so I was thinking of doing it "gradually", from bottom to top. Will I be able to push my next commits if I do that?

Comment: Yes, you can. Git pushes the current head commti and all predecessor commitss that are not yet in the remote repository.